# ECharts Stacked Bar Chart: Setting BorderRadius on Topmost Bar Only

Tags: echarts

I am using [Apache eCharts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) and I have created a [stacked bar chart](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar).

It works, but now I want to put a border radius on the top stacked bar.

I do not want all bars to be rounded, only the very top bar, whatever that may be.

In the image below the stacked bars on the left have a green `2012` which is currently the top stack and correctly rounded using `borderRadius`.

But the right stacked bars do not have a value for `2012` because it is `undefined` for that country. So the top series in that case is actually `2011` which does not get the `borderRadius` applied.

So how do I apply a border radius on the top stacked bar, whatever that may be?

**Here is a [live demo](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsA2BTA5l6AJgFzIC-ANGrGMMBpCCUhVQQIZhsDOWYTV6AhAC2-LlGhcSAbQDkAY2ABXaGABOAT1nlYsgEwAGAIx7tuw0aOyAupXTouytfKwyB9pLEUr1GkrIAhNTYALwgMMwsjEgB2Ax0LPRIAZgNYFnsPL2VVTX8ASUIYLHE2SONo2CMDeNhEkhUCLAAzCGgsAnT3ayoM2AAPAEF-iClkag0QV115DlxgTVl0u1gNYdGmPp41CBK3TNRM9Gg2UX8o7Xd0MEnp2QAjNjVLo9guTnkAa38NLCeuF5HfCKJr8V7ofr-by5LQrV5-cwVWRXLqZProQ5HE5nREmQGZG5TfyPZ5w-zvNhfH5_NQAsnoYHAUHIFEQqE5Xz4o4I_TGUwo9H2CBgLDCADKN2wTFg9wWTTUACU2EIlGNpKkdBrYLUDNZUfZSFQeqQANxAA).**

**See image here:**

[image]

**Here is my current code:**

```JavaScript
option = {
  legend: {},
  tooltip: {},
  dataset: {
    dimensions: ['country', '2012', '2011'],
    source: [
      { country: 'Brazil', 2011: 70, 2012: 30 },
      { country: 'Indonesia', 2011: 100, 2012: undefined }
    ]
  },
  xAxis: { type: 'category' },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: '2011',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'years',
      encode: {
        x: 'country',
        y: '2011'
      }
    },
    {
      name: '2012',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'years',
      encode: {
        x: 'country',
        y: '2012'
      },
      itemStyle: { borderRadius: [30, 30, 0, 0] }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible. The best workaround I can think of is using [`barMinHeight`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.barMinHeight) to always make the top bar appear but this would make the visualization incorrect.

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMmuhgE4QDmFApqYQOQCGAHhAM70A0x6L7ACsAjQwtQqhIkwATxDUGbABaMAJsADu9HrAC-xHd3TZqNaCvEHiFcuaKTjAMzAMAzAFIu28hUXPY9ABYPQxIAI2AwTABbV2DtAGMYMEZhABlGUOpsQjBSAFdqfRDmAEFWNnFtGTkGeMZRCmBSaS10S3RpMvYLELZaCGoK2ABtbQlJWGhGKPl_ABEIUmp4sE8JjFlZ-lDGUjWJtmT4gGsGTGTsffsMrMr19CUNHPzC9faJ6iiQZTZuu3uHMB4nkhvQ-uRBq0Ju9JCp6oxCMMXAAmAAMnFgLlRyIxWIAjLiXAFcQBOdGYrG4tEAXW0MP-kimMwYAFkUthYCUVFcpJsGDs9iFJIdGCczhFGJchSRsDdsgyDoonmQCto2tL0J9voxfkNxutAcDQeCBhw1boNbA4clEXi0Ri8SiHaiCbBHcTYGSMcjKbBkXjUbTJPT9SQmVsSg4HBBsBB6tROdzLdUtgKeQ8jqd_OdJenYLLMvLQ8Klepnqq3patT8_sWSIaQQp-pDzfT0NaESNkfa3QAOHFukmun0e5FeinklwBoMkEPm8MMABqEBU1GAibzKf5uzzIrF2YlUvNBduCpLytyFehVa-Nb15vQDeNzbNlfNHdtAFZyf6B2jXXin4eni44uL6ATTnS0p1gu_gAMrULs8SKLAACi0AUMI1Cbny_hppae5ZvQOZHusJ5Fg-sCPGWKqvNe5rVjqtaUU-TYQq-9HrB-Iz9uSvZOp6LoYiSRIOmO5KOr6gaWgKLLCAAEtQlC-IQgGWhAohRHBMjGHc9zoOEpCrqQABKqgQI2IwBs6GLktJsAAPQOYmKjCBQsCGcZsCkOZIKwIotB0W-wbELSOgANxAA) is an example:

```js
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {},
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [320, 302, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
    },
    {
      name: 'Mail Ad',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      name: 'Affiliate Ad',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
      name: 'Video Ad',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [150, 212, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    },
    {
      name: 'Search Engine',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [820, 832, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 0],
      barMinHeight: 15,
      itemStyle: {
          borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0], // Adding border radius here
        },
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, I also think it's not possible so I'll mark this answer as accepted unless someone else finds a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Turns out this solution isn't great because must know which series will be lowest / highest before you arrange the order of the series. This is because the lowest must at the front. Unfortunately, this makes it unworkable for me because I cannot know that ahead of time.

In [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsA2BTA5l6AJgFzIC-ANGrGMMBpCCUhVQQIZhsDOWYTV6AhAC2-LlGhcSAbQDkAY2ABXaGABOAT1nlYsgEwAGAIx7tuw0aOyAupXTouytfKwyB9pLEUr1GkrIAhNTYALwgMMwsjEgBWAx0LPRIAZgNYFnsPL2VVTX8ASUIYLHE2SONo2AAOeNhEkhUCLAAzCGgsAnT3ayoM2AAPAEF-iClkag0QV115DlxgTVl0u1gNYdGmPp41CBK3TNRM9Gg2UX8o7Xd0MEnp2QAjNjVLo9h8RSb-V_R-_29crQrV5-cwVWRXZYQiBgLDCADKN2wX2-9wWTTUACU2EIlGNpKkdATYLUDD1XqR3H10IcjiczqCTC8jjcpv5Hs8gfZ2QBxNiMXQAWiMBgMAFImZl3sBPsgIT8_jlfBKjiD9MZTBCqfZobCERokbLvrBUWp0VicXiiUSSWSjhTMn0eqQANxAA) it works because `2012` is the lowest value.

But in [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsA2BTA5l6AJgFzIC-ANGrGMMBpCCUhVQQIZhsDOWYTV6AhAC2-LlGhcSAbQDkAY2ABXaGABOAT1nlYsgEwAGAIx7tuw0aOyAupXTouytfKwyB9pLEUr1GkrIAhNTYALwgMMwsjEgBmAx0LPRIAVgNYFnsPL2VVTX8ASUIYLHE2SONo2AAOeNhEkhUCLAAzCGgsAnT3ayoM2AAPAEF-iClkag0QV115DlxgTVl0u1gNYdGmPp41CBK3TNRM9Gg2UX8o7Xd0MEnp2QAjNjVLo9h8RSb-V_R-_29crQrV5-cwVWRXZYQiBgLDCADKN2wX2-9wWTTUACU2EIlGNpHEdATYLUDD1XqR3H10IcjiczqCTC8jjcpv5Hs8gfZ2QBxNiMXQAWiMBgMAFImZl3sBPsgIT8_jlfBKjiD9MZTBCqfZobCERokbLvrBUWp0VicXiiUSSWSjhTMn0eqQANxAA) it does not work because I made `2012` the highest value and now the `2011` series is hidden behind `2012`.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Another solution is to layer the bars using `barGap: '-100%'` instead of stacking.

[Live demo here.](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsA2BTA5l6AJgFzIC-ANGrAB4CC1EAziUrAQIZjskDaA5ACEATuwBeEDH3Kw-ASUIwsjCOykyAqgGVafALqwKVAJ70mLQ-kZYhEJbyrpU6Z7GjsAtlhJ8ATAAYARh8pB2cwIxAvGQAjdiEQl3QOLl4AgA5_AGZpAFdCLAAzCGgsAmkfAE4_TIAWXUpE2AgwLHdNcOwWWGjgIQJrACV2Aggc5lgeAL9pKelp2D99UlCLZydEt09vfwCAhMTwyO9Y-IbEk4BxdhBvAFopvwBSfZdk7gmANiyZzMyfAFZcvkiiUCPVQuhmq12kZOshur1-kIhiMxql5rMFnMliszo4Ia4PFFfIE_C8whFiSdyehLtc7g9nnjnG9eHl-iDStI0n9AbAgtU6szIS02h0oqwen1BsNRuNJhj5kqcS5luhdChSABuIA)

But there are two drawbacks:

1. This rounds all series, not just the top series. It's better than the original problem because the rounded parts will not be white. Instead they take on the background of the layer behind them so it does look better.
2. These bars are not stacked, they are layered. So in this case we have to add the values of all other series that are layered on top to get the correct effect.

It's not exactly what I wanted but it looks better.

Screenshot:

[image]

Example code using data in the series:

```JavaScript
option = {
  legend: {},
  xAxis: { data: ['Brazil', 'Indonesia', 'USA'] },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: '2012',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [18203, undefined, 29034],
      itemStyle: { borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0] }
    },
    {
      name: '2011',
      type: 'bar',
      barGap: '-100%',
      data: [6203, 13325, undefined],
      itemStyle: { borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0] }
    },
    {
      name: '2010',
      type: 'bar',
      barGap: '-100%',
      data: [undefined, 8325, 12034],
      itemStyle: { borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0] }
    }
  ]
};
```

Same outcome using `dataSet` instead of defining data in the series:

```JavaScript
option = {
  legend: {},
  tooltip: {},
  dataset: {
    dimensions: ['country', '2012', '2011', '2010'],
    source: [
      { country: 'Brazil', '2012': 18203, '2011': 6203, '2010': undefined },
      { country: 'Indonesia', '2012': undefined, '2011': 13325, '2010': 8325 },
      { country: 'USA', '2012': 29034, '2011': undefined, '2010': 12034 }
    ]
  },
  xAxis: { type: 'category', },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: '2012',
      type: 'bar',
      itemStyle: { borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0] }
    },
    {
      name: '2011',
      type: 'bar',
      barGap: '-100%',
      itemStyle: { borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0] }
    },
    {
      name: '2010',
      type: 'bar',
      barGap: '-100%',
      itemStyle: { borderRadius: [10, 10, 0, 0] }
    }
  ]
};
```